# Creating a reusable function for AJAX requests

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I'm building a weather app and want to create a reusable function for making AJAX requests, but I can't figure out how to make it work. My code explains what I want better than words. How do I make this function work correctly?

```
fetchWeather(reqCity) {
var city = reqCity
var searchText = ...a lot of stuff
var results

axios.get(`https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=${searchText}&format=json`)
.then(response => results = response.data.query.results.channel.item.condition)

return results //doesn't work because of asynchronicity
}

componentDidMount() {
var weatherInMoscow = this.fetchWeather('Moscow')
this.setState({
  moscow: weatherInMoscow 
})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of number of ways to achieve this. One of the simplest ways is to pass a `callback` function and perform your required actions in the `callback`(cb).

```
fetchWeather(reqCity, cb) {
 var city = reqCity
 var searchText = ...a lot of stuff
 var results

 axios.get(`https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=${searchText}&format=json`)
 .then(response => cb(response.data.query.results.channel.item.condition))
}
```

In the place where you call, you send the callback similar to this and perform the required actions in it.

```
componentDidMount() {
 var weatherInMoscow = this.fetchWeather('Moscow', (data) => {
   this.setState({
    moscow: data 
   })
 })
}
```

**Note:** This code does not show how to handle the error. You need to add you logic in the `cb`(callback) function to handle errors if there are any.